# Creating Surf() with Labels

Tags: matlab

```
[ndata, text, alldata] = xlsread('Euro swap rates.xlsx',3);
%(although created from text dates is still a cell array?) 
dates=text(:,1);  
%(Same problem here)
rates_header=text(1,:);  
rates=ndata;
surf(rates);
colormap(jet);  

>> surf(rates,dates); %but when I try to add wither of the labels I get a problem?
??? Error using ==> surf at 78
X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex.

>> surf(rates,dates,rates_header);
??? Error using ==> surf at 78
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.`
```

I'm assuming the problem is because dates and rates_header are still cell arrays?

How can I convert them to text? Is there a way to do it directly as part of xlsread?

Lastly on the plot I would like to make the first cell in the arrays dates and rates_header, the name for that axis of the surf plot with all the rest of the data being used to populate the axis.

getting closer

> > title('Euro Swap Rates');
> >
> > xlabel('Maturity');
> >
> > ylabel('Date');
> >
> > zlabel('Swap Rate');
> >
> > set(gca, 'YTick', 1:100:length(dates));
> >
> > set(gca, 'YTickLabel', dates(1:100:length(dates)));
> >
> > set(gca, 'XTick', 0:10:length(rates_header));
> >
> > set(gca, 'XTickLabel', rates_header(0:10:length(rates_header)));

Two questions remain:

1. I would like the x Tick to be 1y then 10y20y...60y So that the first step size is 9y then 10y for all remaining points
2. I would like the dates to show the 1st of Jan and ist of June each year only (or the closest working days to those dates).

Comment: I believe they are cell arrays because they ARE text (an array of strings). If you know they are of the right - different - format though, you can convert them to a simple character array using `char(array)`

Comment: Unfortunately the requirement as per the documentation is that `[a b c] = xlsread()` returns a cell array for the text output parameter

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to make the ticklabels = the dates cell array.

Comment: yea I want the x axis to the date labels, the y axis the rate headers and the z axis the rates

Comment: tried using mesh butg I get this error:

Comment: mesh(rates_header,dates,rates);
??? Error using ==> mesh at 80
X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex.

Comment: @HughPatience see the update on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to set the labels on the x-axis.

You don't do this through `surf`, you do it after using `set`, like this:

```
set(axHandle, 'XTickLabel', xlabels);
```

Here is a complete example:

```
[x  y] = meshgrid(-4:.25:4;);
z = x.^2 + y.^2;
xlab = {'one','two','three','four'};

surf(x,y,z);
set(gca,'XTickLabel', xlab);
```

You can use whatever labels you want provided that they are strings and saved to a cell array. This is what I did above for `xlab`.

Comment: getting closer

>> title('Euro Swap Rates');
>> xlabel('Maturity');
>> ylabel('Date');
>> zlabel('Swap Rate');
>> set(gca, 'YTick', 1:100:length(dates));
>> set(gca, 'YTickLabel', dates(1:100:length(dates)));
>> set(gca, 'XTick', 0:10:length(rates_header));
>> set(gca, 'XTickLabel', rates_header(0:10:length(rates_header)));

Two questions remain:

1.) I would like the x Tick to be 1y then 10y20y...60y
So that the first step size is 9y then 10y for all remaining points

2.) I would like the dates to show the 1st of Jan and ist of June each year only (or the closest working days to those dates).

Comment: @HughPatience, code pasted into comments is difficult to read, can you edit  your original question and add the code there?