# Adding labels and axis to Surf in Matlab

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating Surf() with Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821605/creating-surf-with-labels)

```
title('Euro Swap Rates');

xlabel('Maturity');

ylabel('Date');

zlabel('Swap Rate');

set(gca, 'YTick', 1:100:length(dates));

set(gca, 'YTickLabel', dates(1:100:length(dates))); 

set(gca, 'XTick', 0:10:length(rates_header)); 

set(gca, 'XTickLabel', rates_header(0:10:length(rates_header)));
```

Two questions remain: 
1.
2.

1. I would like the `x` Tick to be `1y` then `10y20y...50y` So that the first step size is `9y` then `10y` for all remaining points, apart from the last `2` which are `55y` and `60y` and so should be spaced `5y` apart how can I handle this irregular spacing?
2. I would like the dates to show the 1st of Jan and ist of June each year only (or the closest working days to those dates). (At the moment the code above just takes the length of the vector and splits it as instructed, I need someway where it can look at the values in the array and split accordingly.

OK did it, seems a slightly cackhanded way to do it but its done

```
keydates={'01/01/2000','01/06/2000','01/01/2001','01/06/2001','01/01/2002','01/06/2002','01/01/2003','01/06/2003','01/01/2004','01/06/2004','01/01/2005','01/06/2005','01/01/2006','01/06/2006','01/01/2007','01/06/2007','01/01/2008','01/06/2008','01/01/2009','01/06/2009','01/01/2010','01/06/2010','01/01/2011','01/06/2011','01/01/2012','01/06/2012'};
 keydates2=datenum(keydates,'dd/mm/yyyy');
 dates2=datenum(dates,'dd/mm/yyyy');
 [index]=ClosestDate(dates2,keydates2);
 ytick = index;
 yticklabels = keydates;
 set(gca, 'YTick', ytick); 
 set(gca, 'YTickLabel', yticklabels);
```

ClosestDate is my function that finds the first date in dates2, that is more than each date in keydates2.

Comment: This is similar all be it slightly extended. You answered the original question there correctly so I thought I could close that one and start a new thread, hope I haven't broken any rules?

Comment: Would be much easier to help if you gave some code that would run, even if it doesn't run quite how you like just yet. Please give some example data for `dates` and `rates_header` so I don't have to dream it up

Comment: If you need to delete one please make it the previous one. Sorry again if I breached any rules you guys are very helpful the last thing I want to do is piss you off.

Comment: OK will do but away fom my desk for 2hrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Q1, Just set the `XTick` property exactly as you describe: [EDIT: changed bad use of double quotes (") to single quotes (')]

```
xtick = [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 55, 60];
xticklabels = {'1y', '10y', '20y', '30y', '40y', '50y', '55y', '60y'};

set(gca, 'XTick', xtick);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', xticklabels);
```

It's hard to answer Q2 without information about what the `dates` array contains, but you can do the same thing:

```
ytick = 1:6:60; % or whatever is appropriate according to the scale you are using
yticklabels = {'Jan 2005', 'Jun 2005', 'Jan 2006', 'Jun 2006', ...etc };

set(gca, 'YTick', ytick);
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', yticklabels);
```

Of course you can also generate the strings automatically from the tick values - if you need help to do this just ask for it.

Comment: Thanks the xtick works perfectly, although I had to alter the "1y" etc to '1y' in xticklabels. The problem with the dates is that there are not an equal number of working days in each year depending were w/e falls. I could manually look where the dates are and then enter the ytick manually as you do for xtick, but seems labout intensive. Surely there is a way to search the dates vector for the position of the dates I want and then to use the poitions of those dates in the dates vector to generate ytick. If you can show me how to add files, I'll send an example of the dates file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the double quotes - that's been fixed.  Looks like you solved your problem with the dates, but just as a note, normally axes don't need irregular tick marks.  Just put a sensible scale that's suitable for reading the graph, and if you need to label the data points then do that on the data points, not on the axes.